# Cloudways SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Tags: mysql, laravel

i'm trying to execute database migration in my cloudways server but it returns me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE').
```

[image error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s39nQ.jpg)

I've been deploied my laravel project on cloudways from gitlab repository and i've also edited by cloudways terminal the file `.env` and changed the value `DB_DATABASE` with the name of my database and `DB_USERNAME & DB_PASSWORD` with my database username and password... then, i've wrote and saved with `:w` and `:q` on the console, and then i've launched the command: '`php artisan migrate:fresh`' to migrate my tables but the cloudways console returns me the error which I mentioned above. The same error appear also if i'm trying to logging on mysql in the cloudways terminal with command: '`mysql -u root -p`' (after entering the password). I'm very very very sure that the `DB_DATABASE`, `DS_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` in my `.env` file are correct so I don't understand with i'm doing wrong. Anyone can help me?

Edit: env file here [image .env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sGvG.jpg)

Edit2: mysql authentication method [authentication on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OldS6.jpg)

Comment: show your .env please

Comment: did you clear the configuration cache?

Comment: @albus_severus added env file,
user3532758 no I didn't, how can I do?

Comment: try running 'php artisan config:clear' and then see if migration works.

Comment: @user3532758 configuration cache cleared but not solved error..

Comment: did you update mysql username and password while the web server was running?

Comment: Can you also check which authentication method root uses.. it should be mysql_native_password

Comment: Yes I did because the cloudways tutorial says of launch the composer 'composer update' after entering in the public_html folder

Comment: This is how you check: login to mysql. and run this: 'SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;'  Plugin column will show the authentication methods.

Comment: I did, i've update my post take a look up

Comment: Can you try 'php artisan cache:clear' and if that did not work, try restarting apache if you have not already.

Comment: Cache cleared and apache restarded.. the problem is the same

Comment: I see. Can you disable mysql strict mode temporarily. And see if the error persists.

Comment: How to disable mysql strict mode?

Comment: Try running ' mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';" '

Comment: Did you get it solved?

Comment: No I didn't, on my local computer your command works, but on cloudways terminal it returns me always the same error

Comment: Provide `SHOW GRANTS FOR root@localhost`

Comment: @RickJames your command in local returns me this:
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Looks like you are facing some issues with DB file also. Can you give me your email to check if the problem didn't solve yet? I'm from Cloudways and can help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

TRy this

```
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I did, the problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

`ON .` -- Perhaps you meant `ON *.*` to refer to all tables in all databases.  As it is, you probably have privileges only on the database named `.`

Comment: Yes exactly.. so what can i do?

Comment: @PaoloPrivitera - Add another GRANT with the correct syntax.